# APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to publish an app to google play, and it won't allow me, it says:

```
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not valid. 
You need to sign tour APK with certificate that is currently valid.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I remedy this error?

Comment: create a new certificate/keystore. Somehow your apk has a certificate that is only valid in the future. (aka, the start date is currently in the future).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Doomsknight, where do I set the start date?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Solved it by changing the system date of my computer. I set it to today - 2 days and created a new keystore, tried to upload and it worked.

Comment: So was your system date set wrong to start with? Setting the correct date and time (zone) should work. :) +1

Comment: actually you need to change date and time before you will create certificate itself(not sign the apk), so Google play console will be able to compare start and end date of your signed(certificated) apk. This error happens when you are in different time zone than Google play server, i.e. +11hrs.

Comment: This is very bad solution but worked. actually the reason behind you have wrong timezone in urs system which is not yet reached at your point. you need to fix your timezone and correct the date & time of your system.

Comment: What time zone you use, I try change timezone UTC+0, time -3 hours
not even work.

Comment: Not working for me. i tried setting the time zone 2 days before creating an APK from Unity and uploading it to Google Play. That error ruined my day!

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this gotcha but my solution was different. My system time was valid, but maybe it was several minutes off. Anyway if you run into this message but appear to have a correct system time, here are two things I did which worked

1. Wait several minutes (e.g. search stackoverflow for this)
2. Rename the .apk.

Then try to upload again. It just worked for me the second time.

Another issue I ran into was `ant release` reporting that the keystore was tampered with or my password was incorrect when I [signed](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) my app. All I did was retry a second time and `ant release` just went through.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by waiting ~14 hours. Then the upload worked without changing anything in the apk. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up fixing this issue by fixing the time zone in my clock settings.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the days in your system will not fix it. 
This problem is your windows (or other OS) timezone.

Correct your time zone:

[image]
[image]

Comment: this actually works pretty fine. My Time zone was set as Canada's, Changing back to Pakistan's Worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

just wait a minute or two in most cases.  The time is probably just slightly off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say the others are incorrect but they're mostly describing the same thing. The time stamp used when signing your APK was not "correct" for whichever Google uses to validate. Therefore you create signed packages in the past or future from Googles perspective, most likely future as the message indicates future tense "is not valid *yet*"

It's impossible to give a fixed amount of time by which we all must update our clocks by so what worked best for me was to **just wait until it works**.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjusting the app's availability from 25 years to 24 will solve the problem
[image]