# Uploading apk to google play

Tags: android, certificate, apk, signing

I'm getting this error, can someone help me solve this? I've spent hours creating keystrokes and everything....but still I get this...Thanks if ever.

"You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid."

Comment: Did you check your system clock (and especially date)?

Comment: when creating the certificate there are some options you can set, one is the time you want the sign to last, they suggest to set it to something like 50 years, when did you create the signature key?

Comment: I created my signature key last night. I tried uploading it many times but it keeps on telling me that error. By the way, I set it to 100 years.

Comment: @Yogu Yes sir, I did. Should I set this to a particular time/date?

Comment: Set it to feb 5 2013 and check

Comment: It is now working...Thanks everyone! Yes, I tried setting the date 3 days earlier than the actual date now...

Comment: How sir? I'm sorry, I'm just new to this thing/site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your system clock to like day before and then try to sign it. Pls. refer to the links that i have posted

[APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid)

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your application with a unique signature. Look at the dev website: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue:  [APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid)

The person resolved the issue by correcting their system clock and regenerating the Keystore.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but why was my answer accepted and then removed for the same answer someone posted after?