# Keystroke from google play

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a keystroke from google for my app. When I try to Export signed application package from eclipse, it gives me an option to either create a new keystore or to use an existing one.
As per my understanding I must use the "Base64-encoded RSA public key" that I got from Google. But there is no way I can download the key directly from t[he page where google displays it](http://developer.android.com/images/licensing_public_key.png) for me.

Can someone please let me know if I have to import it in someway or am I missing something?
Or should I just copy paste the key to some (binary) file in my project? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a keystroke from google for my app.
>
> But there is no way I can download the key directly from the page where google displays it for me.

Which page is that? You shouldn't download a key in order to sign your application.

Or do you mean the `debug.keystore` which comes with the installation of the Android bundle? You can use it during development, but you need to create your own key when releasing the App. (Google Play won't accept an `apk` signed with the debug keystore)

If you are not releasing yet and you want to use the debug keytore - search your system for 'debug.keystore'. On Windows it can be in:

```
 C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore
```

The passwords for the keystore and the android alias are `android`.

If however you want to create a new key for yourself - you can do that using the provided `keytool` [as described here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert).

Finally, if you need an additional key for accessing some Google API (eg. Maps) with your App, then from the online developer console you need to create an additional Android key with the same fingerprint, as the one that you are signing the App with. This additional key is typically included in your manifest after that.

For reference, you can create new keys for your App here: https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I was talking about the "Base64-encoded RSA public key" that google gives us on the (secure) developer page. My reputation is not high enough to post a screen shot. But here is a sample image available [link](http://developer.android.com/images/licensing_public_key.png).

Comment: Also I'm looking for the release key and not the debug.keystroke. My question is should we use the release key given by Google or can we generate our own key? And I did sign my app with my private key, but not I get an error saying `"You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid."`

Comment: Read again my answer. You need to generate your own keystore in order to export your App and publish it. What you are reffering to is a licensing key, which is different - [see details about it here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)

Comment: Next.. I referred to this question on SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid). I changed my system date to two days ago[3/29/2014]. But I still get the same error. :(

Comment: Well then the issue is with the keystore that you generated, not the licensing key from Google. Did you change the date after you generated the key? You need to do it before. Also - make sure you give a long validity, eg. 25 years.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I first changed my system time and then generated the key. That fixed the issue!

Comment: No problem, good luck on Google Play! make sure to read the licensing topic too.