# You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid

Tags: android, apk

I have gotten my app ready for distribution but when uploading am getting this frustrating error saying, *"You uploaded an **APK** signed with a certificate that is not yet valid"* . You need to sign your **APK** with a certificate that is currently valid".
Have tried several remedies i found online yet no success. I have changed by time zone severally, renamed my apk, cleaned project, even new keystores for my signed apk.

Is there a sure way to get round this? Please help. I renamed my packaged name earlier. Not sure if it contributed to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid

Comment: none of these solution is working for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid)