# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, developer-console

I am using Unity to publish a game and I keep on getting this error when I upload:

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a certificate that is currently valid.

I've checked several threads, and the problem they seem to target is the system time and date settings, but I double-checked that and it is correct.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the correct date and time of his/her system before generating keystore.
You  can follow the following thread.

[APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191854/apk-signed-with-a-certificate-that-is-not-yet-valid)

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you are signing your APK with has a validity start date past the current date.

Create a new certificate in the same or a new keystore, then update your gradle configuration to point to your newly created key and clean your project before re-creating a new APK (or App Bundle).